# Calculate Mean of Multiply Columns with Condition in R

Tags: r, mean

I want to calculate mean of several variables but with condition, if 2 of those columns have NA, mean will be NA, if less than 2, find mean

```
df <- data.frame(ID = c(1:10),X1 = c(rep(1,5),rep(2,5)),X2 = c(1:10),X3 =   c(1,NA,2,NA,NA,1,NA,2,NA,NA),X4 = c(rep(NA,10)),X5=c(rep(1,5),rep(NA,5)),
             Y1 = c(rep(1,5),rep(2,5)),Y2 = c(1:10),Y3 = c(1,NA,2,NA,NA,1,NA,2,NA,NA),Y4 = c(rep(NA,10)),Y5=c(rep(1,5),rep(NA,5)))

MeanX = round(apply(df[,c(2:6)],1, mean,na.rm = TRUE),2)
MeanY = round(apply(df[,c(7:11)],1,mean,na.rm = TRUE),2)
```

This is output it's incorrect

```
   ID X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 Y1 Y2 Y3 Y4 Y5 MeanX MeanY
1   1  1  1  1 NA  1  1  1  1 NA  1  1.00  1.00
2   2  1  2 NA NA  1  1  2 NA NA  1  1.33  1.33*
3   3  1  3  2 NA  1  1  3  2 NA  1  1.75  1.75
4   4  1  4 NA NA  1  1  4 NA NA  1  2.00  2.00*
5   5  1  5 NA NA  1  1  5 NA NA  1  2.33  2.33*
6   6  2  6  1 NA NA  2  6  1 NA NA  3.00  3.00*
7   7  2  7 NA NA NA  2  7 NA NA NA  4.50  4.50 *
8   8  2  8  2 NA NA  2  8  2 NA NA  4.00  4.00 *
9   9  2  9 NA NA NA  2  9 NA NA NA  5.50  5.50 *
10 10  2 10 NA NA NA  2 10 NA NA NA  6.00  6.00 * This is supposed NA,bc there are 3 columns have NA
```

Because I have a large dataset, for each group sometimes I have to set 6 out of 20,sometimes 1 out of 10, so I can calculate mean, how I can set condition for this case.

Comment: you could try something like `df$meanX = apply(df[, 2:6], 1, function(x) ifelse(sum(is.na(x)) < 2, mean(x, na.rm = TRUE), NA))` where you can replace the 2 with that maximum number of NAs

Comment: `rowMeans` may also be of interest to you.

Comment: It's a little illegible, but should be pretty quick (especially if you convert to a matrix instead of using a data frame): `MeanX = round(rowMeans(df[, c(2:6)], na.rm = TRUE), 2) * c(1, NA)[(rowSums(is.na(df[, c(2:6)])) > 2) + 1]`

Comment: @Gregor - and you can avoid obfuscation if you do it in two statements - `df$meanx <- rowMeans(df[7:11], na.rm=TRUE); df$meanx[rowSums(is.na(df[7:11])) >= 2] <- NA`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a VERY quick (have to run) and dirty solution with `data.table`. But I believe it can be cleaned and built upon to make something that is neat and works well.

```
# Load data.table
require(data.table)
setDT(df)

# Format all columns as as numeric, 
# otherwise mean is not meaningful (see what I did there?)
x.cols <- paste("X", 1:5, sep = "")
y.cols <- paste("Y", 1:5, sep = "")
setDT(df)[, (x.cols) := lapply(.SD, as.integer), .SDcols = x.cols]
setDT(df)[, (y.cols) := lapply(.SD, as.integer), .SDcols = y.cols]

# meanX first mean, and then NA
df[, meanX := mean(c(X1, X2, X3, X4, X5), na.rm = TRUE), by =ID]
df[df[, sum(is.na(c(X1, X2, X3, X4, X5))) > 2, by = ID]$V1, meanX := NA]

# meanY first mean, and then NA
df[, meanY := mean(c(Y1, Y2, Y3, Y4, Y5), na.rm = TRUE), by =ID]
df[df[, sum(is.na(c(Y1, Y2, Y3, Y4, Y5))) > 2, by = ID]$V1, meanY := NA]

# Result
df

    ID X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 Y1 Y2 Y3 Y4 Y5    meanX    meanY
 1:  1  1  1  1 NA  1  1  1  1 NA  1 1.000000 1.000000
 2:  2  1  2 NA NA  1  1  2 NA NA  1 1.333333 1.333333
 3:  3  1  3  2 NA  1  1  3  2 NA  1 1.750000 1.750000
 4:  4  1  4 NA NA  1  1  4 NA NA  1 2.000000 2.000000
 5:  5  1  5 NA NA  1  1  5 NA NA  1 2.333333 2.333333
 6:  6  2  6  1 NA NA  2  6  1 NA NA 3.000000 3.000000
 7:  7  2  7 NA NA NA  2  7 NA NA NA       NA       NA
 8:  8  2  8  2 NA NA  2  8  2 NA NA 4.000000 4.000000
 9:  9  2  9 NA NA NA  2  9 NA NA NA       NA       NA
10: 10  2 10 NA NA NA  2 10 NA NA NA       NA       NA
```

Comment: I see OP meant to have "if less than 2, find mean" I used "less than 3" but that can be adapted.

Comment: it's ok, as soon as I understand, condition sometimes changes

Answer (score 2):

Here is a base R solution.

I think this is conceptually easier if you first go to long format, eg:

```
long <- reshape(df, idvar='ID', varying=colnames(df)[-1], timevar='t', sep='', direction='long')
```

which moves the variable subscripts into a variable `t`. it looks like this:

```
> str(long)
'data.frame':   50 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ ID: int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ t : num  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ X : num  1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ Y : num  1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 - attr(*, "reshapeLong")=List of 4
  ..$ varying:List of 2
  .. ..$ X: chr  "X1" "X2" "X3" "X4" ...
  .. ..$ Y: chr  "Y1" "Y2" "Y3" "Y4" ...
  .. ..- attr(*, "v.names")= chr  "X" "Y"
  .. ..- attr(*, "times")= num  1 2 3 4 5
  ..$ v.names: chr  "X" "Y"
  ..$ idvar  : chr "ID"
  ..$ timevar: chr "t"
```

Then you can write an aggregate function fairly naturally based on your description. This one matches @snoram:

```
f <- function(x) if( sum(is.na(x)) > 2 ) NA else mean(x, na.rm=TRUE)
```

Note that the default behavior of `aggregate` is to skip NAs, but you can change that option:

```
aggregate(cbind(meanx=X,meany=Y)~ID, long, f, na.action=na.pass)
```

which gives:

```
   ID       meanx       meany
1   1 1.000000000 1.000000000
2   2 1.333333333 1.333333333
3   3 1.750000000 1.750000000
4   4 2.000000000 2.000000000
5   5 2.333333333 2.333333333
6   6 3.000000000 3.000000000
7   7          NA          NA
8   8 4.000000000 4.000000000
9   9          NA          NA
10 10          NA          NA
```

You can then `cbind` this back on to your original data frame if you like.

The advantage of this approach is that it should easily deal with X6, X7, and so on if you have those also.

EDIT:

Rereading your question, you might be better off tracking the mean and number of NAs seperately, then post-processing. Here is a quick and dirty example of doing so:

```
>     f <- function(x) c(sum(is.na(x)), mean(x, na.rm=TRUE))
> agg <-    aggregate(cbind(meanx=X,meany=Y)~ID, long, f, simplify=FALSE, na.action=na.pass);
> agg
   ID                    meanx                    meany
1   1                     1, 1                     1, 1
2   2 2.000000000, 1.333333333 2.000000000, 1.333333333
3   3               1.00, 1.75               1.00, 1.75
4   4                     2, 2                     2, 2
5   5 2.000000000, 2.333333333 2.000000000, 2.333333333
6   6                     2, 3                     2, 3
7   7                 3.0, 4.5                 3.0, 4.5
8   8                     2, 4                     2, 4
9   9                 3.0, 5.5                 3.0, 5.5
10 10                     3, 6                     3, 6
> g <- function(x, i) if(x[1] <= i) x[2] else NA
> mapply(lapply, agg[2:3],list(g), c(2,1))
   meanx       meany
01 1           1    
02 1.333333333 NA   
03 1.75        1.75 
04 2           NA   
05 2.333333333 NA   
06 3           NA   
07 NA          NA   
08 4           NA   
09 NA          NA   
10 NA          NA
```

That way, you can specify different numbers of NAs allowed for different columns. Apologies for nested applies.